Jitterbit - How to capture Response header (Location) from redirect URL
I am calling Bullhorn REST API's OAuth Endpoint to get the Authorization Code. However, On calling the endpoint, Bullhorn redirects it to another endpoint which returns code within URL of redirected endpoint.
In Postman, within settings, when I disabled option Automatically follow redirects I was able to capture the code of redirected URL within Response Header's Key - Location.
However, In Jitterbit with Http v2 connector I am not able to capture response header Location or anything related to redirected URL. Its only returning standard response and headers of the called endpoint.
I have attached screenshot of Postman and Jitterbit.



Can someone please help me to understand how this can be done in Jitterbit via Connector/Script (latter if its even possible)
Thanks!
cc: @Ashavan
UPDATED

Bullhorn REST API OAuth
UPDATE 2
As Ashavan rightly mentioned in his comment, Bullhorn docs, they don't support a client credentials or password grant type, so the built-in OAuth support in the Jitterbit's HTTPv2 won't work.
So I tried to use No Auth in HTTPV2 Connection as shown below

And in HTTPV2 GET, Passed the required Query Parameters which I have passed in Postman as shown below

Connected jitterbit script to HTTV2 GET to read headers, but got no value
NOTE: Tried both $jitterbit.target.http.response.header.Location; and $jitterbit.source.http.response.header.Location;

Added transformation post script and did Mirror source schema and auto map.

Finally printed the values mapped using a Variable below is the response I got
Messages logged in post-transformation scripts

code->
Bullhorn_APIAuthorizationResponse->{
  "response": {
    "responseItem": {
      "status": true,
      "properties": null,
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "server",
          "value": "nginx/1.22.1"
        },
        {
          "key": "date",
          "value": "Wed, 01 May 2024 03:50:47 GMT"
        },
        {
          "key": "content-type",
          "value": "text/html"
        },
        {
          "key": "content-length",
          "value": "306"
        },
        {
          "key": "last-modified",
          "value": "Wed, 09 Nov 2022 13:52:34 GMT"
        },
        {
          "key": "etag",
          "value": "\"636bb0a2-132\""
        },
        {
          "key": "accept-ranges",
          "value": "bytes"
        }
      ],
      "responseContent": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Welcome to Bullhorn!</title>\n<style>\nhtml { color-scheme: light dark; }\nbody { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;\nfont-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Welcome to Bullhorn</h1>\n<p>Thank you for using Bullhorn</em></p>\n</body>\n</html>",
      "error": {
        "statusCode": null,
        "details": null
      }
    }
  }
}

As you can see in the above output unlike Postman, I do not get response headers (Location) of the redirected URL, its just printing headers of the base URL.
Complete Jitterbit operation


Fyi, mentioning someone in a question doesn't do anything. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97471/how-can-i-mention-tag-any-user-in-a-post.

It seems you're trying to capture the authorization code in the OAuth 2.0 handshake. The HTTPv2 connector supports OAuth authentication to where you shouldn't need to deal with all of that. You can simply set up the connector to use the endpoint you ultimately plan to call and include the necessary authorization settings in the connector.
You would set the Authorization field to OAuth 2.0 and additional options will open up to enter the needed details. From your screenshot, it would appear you need a grant type of Password Grant to allow a username and password to be entered. More details available here.

Thanks Ashavan for the prompt response. I tried with OAuth2 option in HTTPV2 and removed Query parameters from HTTPV2 GET, post which got below error when I clicked on Test connection and also when I executed the operation. I have attached screenshot of OAut2 settings and also included Bullhorn's Documentation in updated section of my post.
Error: Error Code: Error in execution get activity. Exception is Error occurred while generating access token, please verify the credentials. Error is: .,

If you go through the Bullhorn's documentation, it does not need Client_Secret to get Authorization Code, only parameters required are ClientID, username, password, response_type,action and OAuth2  in Jitterbit asks for ClientSecret which even if I filled it does not work as expected also it does not provide options for other parameters mentioned above. Can you please check updated section for OAuth2 screenshot and let me know If I have missed anything.
Thanks

(1/2) Based on a quick review of the Bullhorn docs, they don't support a client credentials or password grant typ, so the built-in OAuth support in the HTTPv2 won't work for you. What you should do is break up the steps. Have one call to loginInfo to get the needed portion of the base URL; then a call to the authorize endpoint to get the authorization code, which you would save to a global variable; and then a separate call to the token endpoint with the auth code.

(2/2) To access the Location response header after the authorize call, you can use the Jitterbit variables jitterbit.target.http.response.header. or jitterbit.source.http.response.header., depending on whether you're using a Source or Target.

Ashavan! Please refer UPDATE 2 Section of my post, connection is successful, but Jitterbit is still not able to go to redirect URL and print Response headers (Location) Have I missed anything?

To clarify, are you saying that the call to /oauth/authorize is always redirecting? If so, two things to try would be to ensure there is not a redirect_uri request parameter included and to set max-redirect to 0 under Additional Settings in the GET connector. And fyi, based on your current setup, it should be $jitterbit.source.http.response.header.Location that's the correct variable to check, since the GET connector is currently serving as a source in the operation.
If your issue is something else, please expound on it.

Thanks Ashavan! max-redirect property in additional settings worked for me to get the expected value.
